# How to submit a new version when there is a Pending Developer Release version already in iTunesConnect?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

We have version 2.4 of our app already gone live (Ready for sale) in app store. We planned a new update 3.0 to be released on 28th March and it is Apple reviewed and in Pending developer release state, but there is a new feature we need to add to the app. We have created a new build but we do not want to reject the 3.0 because it is already approved and we have to go live something on 28th of March. There is a risk of Apple will not approve the new build in time (we have 6 days to get the approval) if we cancel 3.0 and re-submit it.

How can I submit a new version (lets say 3.0.1) or change the build of 3.0 without removing approved 3.0 build?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't submit for review more than one build at a time.

Just submit your 3.0.1, once it's ready, you will be pushed to the end of the Waiting For Review queue.

I know you have a deadline (28th of March). But you have no other choice.

Either you decide to make the modification on your build and pray that the validation process won't take too long, or you release the already approved 3.0 build.

TBH I would recommend submitting the 3.0.1 build with the feature implemented, if it's necessary for the users/clients.
I submitted an App yesterday, Apple has just approved it this morning.

Have a look at those links :

[Expedited-App-Review](https://mobileroadie.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200091766-Requesting-Expedited-App-Review-on-iTunes)

[How to Minimize App Store Approval Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158268/how-to-minimize-app-store-approval-time)